# ASP.NET Web API 2 - Parsing JSON from a POST method to query database dynamically

Tags: c#, json, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to expose my database such that a POST can be made to my controller that would then be used to build a query. I am using entity framework to build my Data Contexts. The idea here is that the client would pass JSON in the POST body. From there queries will be build using the attributes and values specified in the JSON. The kicker here is that I do not want to hard code values. I would like this to build queries in such a dynamic way that any changes made to the data context will directly be reflected in the code.

For example I would like:

```
[
    {
        "NAME":"Random Name"
    },
    {
        "NAME":"Random Name 2",
        "STATUS":"ACTIVE"
    }
]
```

To translate to something like:

```
var query = FROM d in DataContext 
WHERE (x.NAME == "Random NAME 1") 
OR (X.NAME == "Random Name 2" AND X.STATUS == "ACTIVE")
```

Keeping in mind that there are over 60 possible attributes that could be chosen and the data model may change.

This my thinking is to parse the JSON into an object array, Loop through each object, and then loop through non null attributes of that object to dynamically build a query.

Here is my code with actual variables.

**Controller**

```
    public class AgreementsController : ApiController
    {

        private AgreementRepository agreementRepository;

        public AgreementsController()
        {
            this.agreementRepository = new AgreementRepository();
        }

        public AGREEMENT[] Post([FromBody]AGREEMENT[] Agreements)
        {

            return agreementRepository.PostAgreements(Agreements);
        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
public class AgreementRepository
    {
        private DataBaseEntities db = new DataBaseEntities();

        public AGREEMENT[] PostAgreements(AGREEMENT[] Agreements)
        {
            List<AGREEMENT> a = new List<AGREEMENT>();

            foreach (AGREEMENT agreement in Agreements)
            {
                /////Loop Through Possible Attributes and then 
                /////Build queries based off of non null values.
                ////Append to List and return Agreement[] to controller

            }

            var agmts = a.ToArray<AGREEMENT>();

            return agmts;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the kind of thing that you'd want to use OData for. It appears you're using EF, which I believe supports OData.

It's not JSON, but I assume that's just a means to an end and not a strict requirement. It supports a `$filter` option, which I think is what you're looking for.

[Supporting OData Query Options in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)

Comment: You are correct in that JSON was just a means to an end and I am using EF. I will look into OData, I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: This is fantastic!